# Kendo UI Grid returning json instead of displaying data

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-ui-mvc

I am using the Kendo UI MVC grid. The controller is returning data, but it is not being displayed in the grid. What am I doing wrong?

The Controller

```
 [OutputCache(Duration = 1, VaryByParam = "*")]
    public ActionResult GetIdeasForApproval([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        IdeaResponse response = this.DashBoardService.GetIdeasForApproval();

        IEnumerable<Idea> ideas = response.Ideas;

        Idea viewModel = new Idea();
        JsonResult result = new JsonResult();

        result.Data =
            Json(
                response.Ideas.Select(
                    p =>
                        new
                        {
                            IdeaId = p.IdeaId,
                            Title = p.Title,
                            Description = p.Description,
                            //Photo = Convert.ToBase64String(p.TeamMember.Photo),
                            URL = p.Url ?? string.Empty
                        }));
        result.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;

        return result;
    }


@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Idea>()
.Name("ideas-for-approval")
.Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.IdeaId).Visible(false);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Title).Title("Title");
        columns.Bound(p => p.Description).Title("Description");
        columns.Bound(p => p.Url).Title("URL");
    }
)
 .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Events(events => events.Error("onError"))
        .Read(read => read.Action("GetIdeasForApproval", "Dashboard"))
    )
```

)

returned json

```
{"ContentEncoding":null,"ContentType":null,"Data":[{"IdeaId":431,"Title":"Test","Description":"test","URL":""},{"IdeaId":406,"Title":"Windows 10 For All Developers Test","Description":"Upgrade Windows 7 to Windows 10 for all developers. Test","URL":"https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/features"},{"IdeaId":433,"Title":"Test Title","Description":"Test Description","URL":""}],"JsonRequestBehavior":1,"MaxJsonLength":null,"RecursionLimit":null}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

taking your code and tweaking it just slightly from:

```
 JsonResult result = new JsonResult();

        result.Data =
            Json(
                response.Ideas.Select(
                    p =>
                        new
                        {
                            IdeaId = p.IdeaId,
                            Title = p.Title,
                            Description = p.Description,
                            //Photo = Convert.ToBase64String(p.TeamMember.Photo),
                            URL = p.Url ?? string.Empty
                        }));
        result.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;

        return result;
```

to:

```
 var model =  response.Ideas.Select(p => new {
                                                    IdeaId = p.IdeaId,
                                                    Title = p.Title,
                                                    Description = p.Description,
                                                    //Photo = Convert.ToBase64String(p.TeamMember.Photo),
                                                    URL = p.Url ?? string.Empty
                                                        });
return Json(model.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

I personally would probably also change the signature to be a public `JsonResult` rather than an `ActionResult` (just my preference here)

Hopefully this should work for you. If you need more info let me know and I will expand the answer for you.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I made the changes and it still returns the json.

any other ideas?

Jim

Comment: So what view are you calling to get this grid into the browser?

Comment: The name of the view is _ideasForApproval.cshtml

Comment: so what are you calling in the url? as generally by convention _xxxx.cshtml files are used for partial views.

Comment: Yes, that view is a partial view.  The URL value in the browser when I get the json is http://localhost:55943/DashBoard/GetIdeasForApproval

Comment: Well your link is going to always return a `json` result as that is what you are telling it to go to. It needs to go to a view that is rendering this partial.

Comment: So I understand what you are saying.  I need to create a view, not a partial view, and then have the partial view rendered in the view?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88814/discussion-between-david-shorthose-and-user151190).

Comment: correct. again if you need me to update the answer just let me know.